# Crash when switching between activities on Smartphone but works fine on an Emulator

Tags: android, emulation

So I'm using Android Studio on my PC and im testing the app in an emulator which works totally fine.
But when i try to use my smartphone connected to the pc, the app always crashes, when i try to switch the activity.

Everything else seems to work fine. 
Anyone knows why this could be happening?

Thats the exception, that i get when the app chrashes:

```
[ 01-08 16:31:19.455  2922: 2922 E/         ]
                                                                           process stopped due to unexpected signal 13
E/HAL: load: id=gralloc != hmi->id=gralloc
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
I/System: core_booster, getBoosterConfig = false
I/System: core_booster, getBoosterConfig = false
I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
I/art: Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 20(944B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 4% free, 240MB/252MB, paused 251us total 9.704ms
I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 11(12KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 4% free, 240MB/252MB, paused 252us total 16.452ms
I/art: Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 91MB allocation
I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 11(352B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 4% free, 240MB/252MB, paused 343us total 16.178ms
W/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 96412692 byte allocation with 12582912 free bytes and 15MB until OOM"
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, post Exception

Comment: Without seeing the stacktrace of the exception nobody can help you. Please edit it into your question.

Comment: You ran out of memory.  Devices have different amounts of memory, so this isn't surprising that you crash on devices but not the emulator.  To fix it, figure out where you're using all your memory and take steps to reduce it.

Comment: So what your saying is, that i have to find parts in my coding that are too complex and taking too much memory?

Comment: Ok i have found a solution thanks to your help. Thanks a lot!